# PG operator does not exist: uuid = text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have model `Conversation`, `User`, which are connected by `has_many *, through: users_conversations`.

I have this scope:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_conversations
  has_many :users, through: :users_conversations

  scope :by_participants, ->(ids) {
    joins(:users).where("users.id = ALL (ARRAY[?])", ids)
  }
end
```

It is expected to find conversations, in which all of required users participate (strictly).

```
Conversation.by_participants first 
     Failure/Error: its(:first) {is_expected.to eq(@conversation)}

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: uuid = text
       LINE 1: ...= "users_conversations"."user_id" WHERE (users.id = ALL (ARR...
                                                                    ^
       HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
       : SELECT  "conversations".* FROM "conversations" INNER JOIN "users_conversations" ON "users_conversations"."conversation_id" = "conversations"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "users_conversations"."user_id" WHERE (users.id = ALL (ARRAY['7c1a06c8-10c7-417f-96ea-c9c50fcaed35','8af2beca-d5f2-48d7-9857-7b5d124eaac1']))  ORDER BY "conversations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
     # ./spec/models/conversation_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I tried to inject into array `cast (*) as uuid`, but PG seems to consider this as just string:

```
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
       : SELECT  "conversations".* FROM "conversations" INNER JOIN "users_conversations" ON "users_conversations"."conversation_id" = "conversations"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "users_conversations"."user_id" WHERE (users.id = ALL (ARRAY['cast (6d4ff0b3-e148-40f8-87b5-d4d03577577a as uuid)','cast (432f4f6e-5832-4831-80dc-c747b8d3e742 as uuid)']))
```

Comment: Did you try ANY ( `joins(:users).where("users.id = ANY (ARRAY[?])", ids)` ) instead of ALL ?

Comment: @imechemi, it is unlikely to fix the problem and also is not what I need

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_conversations
  has_many :users, through: :users_conversations

  scope :by_participants, ->(ids) {
    joins(:users).where("users.id = ALL (ARRAY[?]::uuid[])", ids)
    # it's all about ARRAY[?]::uuid[] type cast
  }
end
```

Your target column is `::uuid[]` but source is `text`, just type cast and see the result.